# Connection between Loshon Hakodesh and other languages

Tags: hebrew, language, messianic-redemption, golus-exile

I remember finding seforim saying

1. All languages are really just a distortion of Loshon HaKodesh
2. It's as if Loshon Hakodesh is in gallus (exile) within those other languages. When we identify how a word in another language is really connected to Loshon Hakodesh, it's bringing Loshon Hakodesh out of exile. It brings the world, and the Jewish people, closer to geulah (the final redemption).

These were in different seforim.

I think the first idea was in Michtav M'Eliyahu, but I was never able to find it again when looking for it.

I think the second was in Yad Malachi or a similar type of book that gives general rules about the language used in the Gemara. But here, too, I've looked and looked and haven't been able to find the quote again.

Do you know where any sefarim mention these ideas?

Comment: There was a whole book on this in yeshiva, that was basically a list of English words and their supposed Hebrew root. Perhaps a tad fanciful, but if I remember it would you like to know about it?

Comment: Yes, that sounds interesting.

Comment: I _think_ it was this: https://www.amazon.com/WORD-DICTIONARY-REVEALS-HEBREW-ENGLISH/dp/1561719420#:~:text=THE%20WORD%20is%20a%20unique,engineered%20dynamics%20of%20human%20language., but without being able to look inside I can't promise. It's classed under "christian books" but that doesn't necessarily mean anything. The page itself seems to indicate it's a Jewish book (read the editorial review)